# Reading and writing registry returns error

Tags: c#, windows, forms, registry, key

Well, I'm trying to write/read a SubKey on my application, but it give me a error.

```
Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\SAMP", true).SetValue("PlayerName", textBox1.Text);
string gamePath = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\SAMP").GetValue("gta_sa_exe").ToString();
```

The error is on the first line:

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Sorry, but I am pretty newbie on C# and just can't figure it out.

Comment: If you are running a 32-bit exe on a 64-bit OS [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3655968/2065121) for some relevant information.

Comment: Nope, it's a 32 bit app, and it is on the right key.

Answer (score 0):

you try to get non existing key.
you should create the key before you try to get it.

here is a sample code

```
 Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("Software\\SAMP");
            Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\SAMP", true).SetValue("PlayerName", "tremp");
            string gamePath = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\SAMP").GetValue("PlayerName").ToString();
```

Comment: Are you sure is exists in LocalMachine? maybe in other root?

Comment: Yes I do, actually the SetValue in PlayerName subkey works, but on get the value of "gta_sa_exe" subkey, crashes my app and returns me that error.

Comment: So thats your answer, the OpenSubKey fails to find the subkey, returns a null, and when you try to convert the null to a string you get the exception.

Comment: So, how can I fix that?

Comment: Try splitting your statement up into separate assignments, you've currently got an OpenSubKey, a GetValue, and a ToString all on the same line. Split them up, then see which line fails.

Comment: Ok so you're probably accessing textbox1's Text property before textbox1 is initialized. Make sure you only access it after your constructor has called InitializeComponent.